# Linear regression - moving independent and dependent columns for each run

Tags: r, for-loop, regression, sapply

I am struggling with solving this problem:

Let's say I have `data("mtcars")` dataframe. I would like to perform regression for two columns of this dataframe (e.g. `mtcars$mpg` versus `mtcars$wt`), store R-squared of each regression and residuals of each regression into two different dataframes, then move the columns to the right for both independent and dependent variables (e.g. `mtcars$cyl` versus `mtcars$qsec`). I will need to repeat this until I reach the last independent variable column (in this `mtcars` database it would be `drat` column).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: which are the dependent and independent variables.  Your description is confusing.  If you can show an example of what you wanted to do, it would be more useful

Comment: columns on the left are dependent. Independent columns are on the right (e.g. `mtcars$mpg` is dependent versus `mtcars$wt` independent).

Comment: Some things are not clear `I will need to repeat this until I reach the last independent variable column `

Comment: I was thinking specifically subsetting the dataframe into independent and dependent, and then performing regression. Most of the time, the number of columns are equal (i.e. I would usually have 58 independent and 58 dependent variable columns). However, if I will have more dependent columns than independent, I would like to stop at the latest available independent (i.e. let's say I have 60 dependent and 58 independent -- for this I would like to have only 58 regressions). I hope this is clear. Let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rollapply over a column index.  List(c(-5, 0)) means use offsets -5 and 0 on each iteration.

```
library(zoo)

resids <- t(rollapply(1:ncol(mtcars), list(c(-5, 0)), 
  function(ix) resid(lm(mtcars[, ix]))))

rsquareds <- rollapply(1:ncol(mtcars), list(c(-5, 0)), 
  function(ix) summary(lm(mtcars[, ix]))$r.squared)
```

If you meant to reverse which are the dependent and independent variables then use `list(c(0, -5))` instead.

Comment: Thank you! Will try this out using `mtcars` dataset.

Comment: Looks great! Is it possible to incorporate a maximum number of regression to be run on the columns depending on minimum number of available dependent and independent variable columns? I.e. run `x` number of regression, where `x = min(cols_depenedent, cols_independent)`? I will supply `cols_depenedent` and `cols_independent`.

Comment: If you just want to use columns 1:3, 5:7 then use `mtcars2 <- mtcars[c(1:3, 5:7)]` instead of `mtcars` and `list(c(-3, 0))`.